# How to load Transform from a file in to Recognizer in Sphinx4-5prealpha

Tags: transform, sphinx4

Usaing sample code TranscriberDemo.java I successfully save Transform in to a file as follows:

```
// Transform represents the speech profile
Transform transform = stats.createTransform();
transform.store("MyVoiceTransform", 0);
```

Now I want to use it in another program, how do I load Transform from file in to Recognizer ? 
I tried below code, but its throwing **java.lang.NullPointerException** at **transform2.load("MyVoiceTransform");** 
I think this is not the way of loading Transform from file. 
Could you point me to correct code ?

```
StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer2 = new      
StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
Stats stats2 = recognizer2.createStats(1);
Transform transform2 = stats2.createTransform();
transform2.load("MyVoiceTransform");
recognizer2.setTransform(transform2);
```

and this code

```
StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer2 = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
recognizer2.loadTransform("MyVoiceTransform", 1);
```

I am using sphinx4-5prealpha.

Comment: It might be a bug, I can look a bit later.

Comment: I tried a lot and debug the code of load() in Transform Class, One thing is sure that Scanner is not working as expected, I wrote my own load() function and use it. It is working but the results are not good with Transform load. Whats your thought on Transform?

Comment: @Nikolay When I expect a resolution?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't have time yet, maybe over weekend. It would be helpful if you file an issue on github on this. Thanks.

Comment: ok. done.
https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/issues/40

Comment: Hello @Nikolay, any update on this issue?